# Isomorphism between $R$ and its dual space

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$. If $f$ is an $R$-module monomorphism from $R$ to the dual $K$-space $\operatorname{Hom}_K(R,K)$ why it is onto? Thanks!

Comment: How is $K$ an $R$-module?

Comment: Sorry! I edited the question.

Comment: It's because every $R$-module map is a $K$-module map, and an injection of $K$-modules of the same (finite) rank is an iso, since $K$ is a field.

Comment: And why the dual space has the same rank of $R$?

Comment: This is from linear algebra. Given a basis $e_i$ of $R$ over $K$, the dual basis $e_i^\ast(e_j)=\delta_{i,j}$ is a basis of $R^\vee$ of the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:R\to\operatorname{Hom}_K(R,K)$ be an $R$-module monomorphism. This is also a $K$-vector space monomorphism. Since $R$ is a finitely dimensional $K$-vector space, $\dim_KR=\dim_KR^*$, and thus every monomorphism of $K$-vector spaces $R\to R^*$ must be an isomorphism.